# ubuntu 16.04 refuses to run with GEForce GTX1650

Tags: drivers, nvidia

Since I replaced my video card from a GEForce 750Ti to a GEForce GTX1650 all I got was a black screen. Not being a computer wizard, I ended up reloading Ubuntu. I now have nouveau drivers that won't work the video card and Ubuntu will not allow me to load nvidia drivers

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of reading and trying many things including trying to load 18.04 I tried 'xrandr' and was informed there was no graphics card. I replaced the GTX1650 with the old GTX750ti , reinstalled 16.04, nvidia driver(384) installed and resolution went from 1360x768 to 1600x900 as it should be. Problem solved for me for the time being.